# Uploading a file with Rails and ExtJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs, extjs4

I am building RoR project with ExtJS on the client side, but I need uploading a file for process on the server side.

Please anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance

Note: I using ExtJS 4 with the new MVC pattern...

Answer (score 0):

On client side you can use [Ext.form.field.File](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.File) (There is good example illustrating how to use this widget).

[This tutorial](http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent) may help you in organizing server side.